# Separated columns output for matrix of strings

Tags: matlab, matrix, output, octave

Let a matrix with string values be defined as such:

```
A = ["abc" "abd" "e"];
```

Octave prints it like:

```
A = abcabde
```

While I need a separated view:

```
A = abc abd e
```

Is any way to achieve it?

**UPD**: I can't use `{"abc" "abd" "e"}`, because in this case I can not use `perms(A)` function - it will give a wrong result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about octave but MATLAB allows permuting strings in a cell array with 'perms'. If Octave doesn't, how about permuting indices in an cell array of strings instead?

```
A = {'abc', 'def', 'g'};
idx = 1:3;
idx2 = perms(idx);

>> A(idx2)

ans = 

    'g'      'def'    'abc'
    'g'      'abc'    'def'
    'def'    'g'      'abc'
    'def'    'abc'    'g'  
    'abc'    'def'    'g'  
    'abc'    'g'      'def'
```

Comment: You're right, `perms` works for cell arrays in octave as well. Only OP has problems understanding the output.

Comment: @AndrasDeak can you help with formatting? How can I archive same view in octave?

Comment: @AndrasDeak great! Thank you very much

Comment: @Andremoniy Wait, what I wrote screws up the order, it won't go column-wise. You have to transpose `A` and then use that. Solution: `printf('%-3s %-3s %-3s\n',A(perms(1:length(A))'){:})`.